# DateTime.ToString()?

Tags: c#, string, date

I am having a problem. How do I show the text of my Date correctly?

using `DateTime.Now` I was able to recieve the date & time the computers clock is set to currently, however, when I try to parse into a string format, it also shows the date like: 12-04-2012 12:38 **but** I was trying to get the time string only, like **12:38** only?

What I tried so far was `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("00:00:00"));`

But it did not work =/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`DateTime` has  a [`ToShortTimeString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshorttimestring.aspx) method defined:

```
DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()
```

Or, you can use a [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm")
```

Alternatively, use the [standard format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) for [short time format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#ShortTime):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("t")
```

Comment: Note, if you use `"HH:mm"`, the colon `:` will be "translated" into the time separator of the current thread's culture. Like if that culture is "Bengali (India)" (`new CultureInfo("bn-IN")`), ouput would become `14.26` because that culture uses a dot as time separator. If you don't want that, escape your colon, as in `DateTime.Now.ToString(@"HH\:mm")`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - the standard format strings, as well as `ToShortTimeString` are _all_ culture sensitive as well.

Comment: Sure. But maybe strings like `"HH.mm"` or `@"HH\:mm"` are culture INsensitive, and sometimes you want that. However, if in doubt, use `InvariantCulture` as format provider together with your custom format string.

Answer (score 7):

One solution that works for a lot of problems is reading documentation :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Using Format "t" seems to do what you want

Answer (score 4):

For using `DateTime.Now.ToString()`, this link is very useful and explains all patterns: http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm

Patterns are like following:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

Tuesday, 22 August 2006 06:30:07

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'")
```

Tue, 22 Aug 2006 06:30:07 GMT

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

08/22/2006

Comment: Note that / in format string represent date separator which is culture specific.

`System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fi-FI");
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));`

08/22/2006
08.22.2006 <= !!!`

Answer (score 2):

Just use this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm");
```

or

```
DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
```

Comment: But remember that `"hh"` is the 12-hour system hours, so e.g. 14:08 would print as `02` (meaning 2 p.m.).

Answer (score 1):

Try to format like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss"));
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm"));
```

But my favorite is

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

var dt = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
dt.ToString().Substring(0, 5);