# Convert to regular date, time and AM or PM

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to convert a date that is returned to me with it in this format:

2022-02-09T14:43:32

I am trying to get it to look like this

2/9/2022 2:43PM

I tried this but it says it is not a valid format.

```
workRow["ShiftStart"] = DateTime.ParseExact(theTempsDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["shiftStartTime"].ToString(), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mmtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString();
```

Comment: Note that `DateTime` does not have a format.  Formats are just for the string representation of the date (parsing from or formatting to).  So you just need to parse your `DateTime` with the correct format and then whenever you need to display it format it with the other format.

Comment: Why are you calling `.ToString()` on `theTempsDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["shiftStartTime"]` only to parse it again. What type is `theTempsDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["shiftStartTime"]`?

Comment: Also, [DateTime.ToString()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11935584/215552), or any of the other questions asked about how to format a DateTime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var dtStr="2022-02-09T14:43:32";
var dt=  DateTime.Parse(dtStr);
dtStr = dt.ToString("M/d/yyyy h:mmtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or who loves in one line

```
var dt=  DateTime.Parse("2022-02-09T14:43:32").ToString("M/d/yyyy h:mmtt", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```

Comment: The one line solution works thank you. I had to change the HH to h but beyond that it worked great. Again thank you.

Comment: You are welcome! I guess h works better for you. I fixed the answer

Answer (score 0):

`ParseExact` should have date format to parse date from file. So, it should have "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:ss:mm" date format. After parsing it will be in DateTime type. To convert it back to string, you can call `.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy hh:mmtt")` on that. Where `"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mmtt"` is your custom date format

Answer (score -1):

You just have to use the right datetime format :

`DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2008, 1, 1, 18, 9, 1, 500); Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt",CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")));`

**Read:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#tSpecifier